# URL and Sample Payload to update NIFI Parameter

Tags: apache-nifi, rest

I am using NiFi parameters and I want to update the value of the NIFI parameter on the fly using NIFI REST API.

But, I could not Identify the URL and the payload format that I have to use in order to update the Parameter.

Lets Assume that I am storing the auth token in the parameter named "MY_TOKEN", what is the API URL that i should use to update the value of this parameter and what is the payload that I have to use to update the parameter?

Comment: Open devtools network in your browser. Update the required parameter and in devtools you could find everything you need.

Comment: @daggett I tired the devb tools. Copied the URL and Payload and tried to replicate the  update via API & payload vis postman, it is not accepting it. Would be great of you could provide a sample record.

Comment: you have to increment a version - that's the usual issue. if it's not working - edit your question, provide all the parameters you are setting in postman and the error message from server.

Comment: @daggett It started working when I tried in a different NiFI Instance.

Comment: @daggett Can you please also look into the below question which I posted regarding NiFi.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732704/how-to-add-or-install-a-patch-in-apache-nifi