# How to add or install a patch in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, snmp-trap

I am having a requirement to send and receive SNMP TRAP via NiFI, Currently NiFi supports only SNMP get/set.

[image: snmp]

I found the below URL where a patch has been available to enable the functionality of SNMP Trap.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7465

But, I do not know how to install this patch in Nifi. The latest release of Nifi is not including this patch.

Can anyone advise me how can I manually install this Patch in Nifi.
I tried to inject the compiled class files into Nifi Nar library file and restarted the nifi instance. But it is not showing up in the processors.

Comment: Did you put the custom nar file into `lib` directoy?

Comment: You need to build a new SNMP nar file for new changes from here - 
https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/5088

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I will try to build the NAR file and replace it in my nifi file system. Thanks for your guidance.